# After adding two conditions in a "for" loop in C I am getting errors

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am getting this error message while trying to run the following program "relational comparison result unused".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0, j = 0; i < 10, j < 3; i++, j++)
    {
        printf("%i %i\n",i, j);
    }
}
```

I am expecting a result

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
```

Comment: What result are you actually expecting? The loop will increase i and j at the same time, so something like 0,0 / 1,1 / 2,2?

Comment: You are using the comma operator. You do not have 2 conditions for the loop, you have one: j < 3. The comma operator evaluates i < 10 and discards the result. You probably meant  i < 10 && j < 3

Comment: `i < 10, j < 3; `does not do what you think.

Comment: yes, I am expecting the same result but it is showing an error @Joachim Isaksson

Comment: The output I want is exactly what you said but it is showing an error. What is the issue? @JoachimIsaksson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After adding two conditions

It's not two conditions, you probably need `i < 10 && j < 3`.

> relational comparison result unused

As [user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109) mentioned, it's because the compiler discards the result of `i < 10` caused by the comma, so you need to change it to `i < 10 && j < 3`.

> I am expecting a result 0 0, 1 1, 2 2

Actually, I'm getting this result.

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
```

Comment: The relational comparison result that is unused is `i < 10`. That's because the comma operator evaluates `i < 10`, discards the result, then evaluates `j < 3` and  uses that result.

Comment: No, I am expecting a result
0 0,
1 1,
2 2,